# Use another colour for highlighting a permalink chat message

Tags: feature-request, chat, design, permalink

The yellow is only somewhat disruptive when it's a single line message, but with larger messages it hurts my poor eyes.

Can you pick another colour?

> [image: screenshot of permalink chat message]

Answer (score 4):

Green is a better color for highlighting messages in chat, because [green causes lesser strain on the eyes.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17161/does-green-cause-less-eye-strain)

A sample with green:

[image]

instead of the current yellow highlight:

[image]